# Font on production build different from font in development build Next.js

Tags: css, next.js

as you can see from the images below, the font in my Production Build and Development build for my Next.js webpage differs. After I run `npm run build` and `npm start` to test the production build, the Montserrat Font no longer appears on my webpage.

This was the way I imported the font into my `globals.scss` file. Do let me know if I'm doing anything wrong:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color:  hsl(265, 3%, 53%);
  color: black;
  &:before{
    content:'';
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

Screenshot of Production Build:

[image: Production Build]

Screenshot of Development Build:

[image: Development Build]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to a font to the entire Next.js app in production, You can use custom `Document`. Here you have [link_1](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization) and [link_2](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document), you can read about it.

Example code snippet. `_document.js` file.

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

CSS from `globals.css` file.

```
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```